# MsgBox code not working

Tags: excel, vba

In Macros, on my device, when I enter "MsgBox" with some number or text, as soon as I move to next line it automatically changes to "msgbox" and when executed it starts giving an error at this line. How do I fix This?

```
Sub msgbox()

    msgbox "hello"

End Sub
```

Comment: Name the sub something other than `msgbox`.

Comment: thanks, it worked ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub MsgBox_test()

    MsgBox "hello"

End Sub
```

Referencing the **same function** name within your function is called recursion, and it requires an end case.

Any time you see a recursion, you need to see an `If` statement that applies an end case for some combination of parameters.

An Example recursion:

```
Function Fibonacci(ByVal n As Integer) As Integer
    If n <= 2 Then Fibonacci=1 Else Fibonacci=Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2)
End Function
```

Meaning, that if n is less than 2 then the function would return an actual number.

in your case, the recursion never ends, and this causes a `Stack Overflow` exception.